# Get current weather in Azure App Logics

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to get the current weather for my location in a Azure App Logic workflow. Does one know where to find the documentation about the configuration of the trigger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting weather details in a logic app is easy. Create a logic app with HTTP Request and Response template ,and add an action and search for **weather.** You will get the MSN Weather connector with list of its actions. [image] y

Choose the **Get Current Weather** action. In the HTTP Request connector,create a sample payload to pass a city name during logic app trigger. After you create a sample payload the dynamic value should be available in the expression. Choose it in the Location parameter and save the logic app. Finally in the response body choose the dynamic values as per your need. [image]

Here's the result.[image]